# how to use scrapy to scrape local htm files?

Tags: html, web-scraping, scrapy

I try to use scrapy on a local htm file. I used the url file:///path_to_local_file but the scrapy parser seems to output empty content from the response. What should I do?
Thanks!

[EDIT:when I try to open up the local file with the browser, a window pops up with this info(click me). Is that the reason why my response is empty on scrapy?
Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skbcf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set up a server to be able to use the method you are attempting.

However, you can always upload the file you want to parse to a free hosting service such as

[000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/)